# my modem cannot connect in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: internet-connection

Need help in connecting modem in Ubuntu 12.10! 
how to connect vodafone usb stick modem in ubuntu 12.10. In ubuntu 11.10 it works, then I try in the same way in ubuntu 12.10 but it doesnt work. Do you have a solution?
I am from Indonesia, I use sim card 3 as my provider.

Comment: I see you didn't specify your question. You should specify what type of Vodafone modem do you have. In Indonesia, we now have http://modemlinux.wordpress.com/daftar-tutorial-modem-linux/ as big database for tutorial (including Vodafone-bundled) installing any USB modem sold in Indonesia.

Comment: i am from indonesia too, i also have problem with my modem .
try to use sakis3g, it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "pppoeconf" command without double quotes in root.
It will scan for every internet connection of your computer give yes when it provide dialog box and then after completing scanning restart your computer.
Then , it will automatically connect to internet just click on web browser.

Comment: after I do that, the output is "Sorry, I scanned 3 interfaces, but the Access Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please check your network and modem cables. Another reason for the scan failure may also be another running pppoe process whic controls the modem". Then I restart and still cannot connect.